# How do I update my symfony module with my changes only?

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a very big problem with symfony module generation as i always make modification in my database (add tables , add columns, changes names, changes columns data-type .....) and i want a good way to build the symfony module without any effect on the modules that i didn't change it and without drop the data in the database... on brief i need to update my symfony module with my changes ONLY.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean "models" instead of "modules" here.

If this is the case, basically once you've got data in the database that you don't want to drop:

1 - Make any needed changes to your schema.yml

2 - Use MySQL ALTER TABLE etc to make changes directly to your database

3 - Use the following commands to regenerate your models:

```
symfony doctrine:build --model
symfony doctrine:build --sql
symfony doctrine:build --forms
symfony doctrine:clean-model-files // to clean up old stuff
```

Assuming you haven't made changes to your base classes (which you shouldn't do), the rebuilding of the models shouldn't break anything. You're basically re-building everything but only the changes you introduced in your schema will be introduced.

Comment: Yes i know this solution and i don't want it , i don't want to make changes in my schema i want to make the changes in my database and build the model from it direct and this always drop the database and that what i don't want. the modification in schema.yml is very difficult in case of huge database with a lot of tables and columns.

Comment: @developer: In this case, I would suggest that you look into "symfony doctrine:build-schema" to build the schema file from your database.

Comment: when i build the schema from the database i have some problems with the created at and deleted at columns the schema deal with them as normal records and i have to edit in the schema to fix this and that take a lot of time specially in case of huge database and a lot of tables i don't know if it can be done using script or anything else i need your thinks to help me and thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: @developer: I personally don't know of any other solution. I'm not sure what you mean exactly by a "huge database"... to be honest, I can't actually envisage a situation where the database would be so big that putting in an hour or two into sorting your schema.yml wouldn't be worth it.